# IKVM converted jar to .net with data resources

Tags: .net, ikvm

We have a jar package, converted in .Net DLL library using IKVMC.
(ikvmc mylib.jar -target:library -out:mylib)
We can name it Converted.dll

This Jar contains some resources ".cfg" data.

When using the DLL inside the main application, a test console .net, it's all ok...
We can name it Caller.exe

We moved (referenced) the .Net converted DLL inside another DLL library, to wrap and expose only some methods.
We can name it WrapperOfConverted.dll

So in Caller.exe we reference WrapperOfConverted.dll instead of Converted.dll

Now when we call from the console application (Caller.exe) the wrapper (WrapperOfConverted.dll), it is not capable to load the ".cfg" data files (they are inside the Converted.dll).

It's strange... maybe we have to convert in some specific way?

UPDATE:

In Caller, inside bin\debug, I have the referenced WrapperOfConverted.dll, and Converd.dll (referenced by WrapperOfConverted.dll)

Decompiling with ILSpy the Converted.dll, I can clearly see inside dll a "Resources" folder, inside there is a file with the name of the original jar, ILSpy mark this file as embedded/public. I can save this file from ILSpy. Saved as jar file. Unzipped. Inside there is the structure of the original jar, all folder with classes are empty, but the resource folders, with cfg files, are full of the files.

So the data cfg are present inside Converted.dll, but WrapperOfConverted.dll cannot access it. That's only if there is a triple reference (Caller REFERENCES WrapperOfonverted REFERENCES Converteed)
If I directly from Caller REFERENCE Converted, all seems OK.

Another strange thing: I tried to reference also Converted inside Caller, call some generic method of converted first, when Caller then call some methods of WrapperOfConverted, and WrapperOfConverted calls inside itself methods of Converted, the problem is not present anymore, it sees the cfg data file!

Comment: What do you mean by "We moved the .Net converted DLL inside another DLL library"?

Comment: Sorry for the bad explain... We created a new library, referenced the converted library inside the new library, exposed some methods in the new library, inside these methods we do something and then we call the methods of the converted library.